# Pjax обновление нескольких независимых блоков в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

Учу Yii2 и решил ознакомиться с работой технологии Pjax на сайте: https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-vnikaem-v-pjax.html. Там есть пример "Несколько независимых блоков". Но реализовано оно в ознакомительном варианте и не совсем правильно, о чём и написано ниже. В данном примере в одном *actionMultiple* вычисляются и хеш и ключ, а нужно делать в разных экшенах. Так что решил сделать так, как было бы правильно и столкнулся с тем, что что при клике на ссылку перенаправляет на новую страницу с генерацией либо хеша, либо ключа. Нужно же, чтобы всё было на одной странице и без перезагрузок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код контроллера:

```
public function actionMultiple()
    {
        $security = new Security();
        $randomString = $security->generateRandomString();
        $randomKey = $security->generateRandomKey();
        return $this->render('multiple', [
            'randomString' => $randomString,
            'randomKey' => $randomKey,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionString()
    {
        $security = new Security();
        $randomString= $security->generateRandomString();
        return $this->render('_randomString', [
            'randomString' => $randomString,
        ]);
    }
    public function actionKey()
    {
        $security = new Security();
        $randomKey = $security->generateRandomKey();
        return $this->render('_randomKey', [
            'randomKey' => $randomKey,
        ]);
    }
```

view multiple:

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\Html;

?>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?= Html::a("Новая случайная строка", ['site/string'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary']) ?>
    <h3><?= $randomString ?></h3>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?= Html::a("Новый случайный ключ", ['site/key'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary']) ?>
    <h3><?= $randomKey ?><h3>
            <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```

view _randomString:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

?>

<?= Html::a("Новая случайная строка", ['site/string'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary']) ?>
<h3><?= $randomString ?></h3>
```

view _randomKey:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

?>

<?= Html::a("Новый случайный ключ", ['site/key'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary']) ?>
<h3><?= $randomKey ?><h3>
```

Прошу подсказать мне, что я делаю не так.

Comment: Есть ли ошибки в консоле?

Comment: Не было. Решил задачу другим способом.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1.** Использовать обычный ajax

```
$.ajax({
    'success': function(data){
        var targets = [
            '#container1',
            '#container2'
        ];
        $.each(targets, function (ind, t) {
            $(t).html($(data).find(t).html());
        });
    }
});
```

**Вариант 2.** Использовать pjax, но будет 2 запроса

```
$.pjax.reload({container: "#container1", async:false});
$.pjax.reload({container: "#container2", async:false});
```

P.S. К [разработчикам Pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=multiple+containers) обращаются с 2012г с просьбой сделать 1 запросом, делать не планируют